# How to force changes elsewhere if class changes?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, design-patterns

In my application I have the option to export/import certain classes. It requires a little more than simple json serialize/deserializing.

Lets say I have a Company class like this

```
public class Company
   string Name
   List<Employee> Employees
   CEO Ceo
```

I have an Export() method and I wanted to add a unit test. So I created a test where I arrange a Company, export it and assert some things. Details aren't important.

Now, if I come back in 2 weeks and add a new class Department to my application and a List of Departments to my Company, I need to extend the Export() method as well.

There are 2 problems with this. 1) I need to remember to extend my Export() method. 2) My test won't actually break. I cannot assert for the existence of a property which I don't even know is gonna exist in 2 weeks.

This test is worse than no test. It gives a false sense of security.

I actually wrote a new version of the export method, which should not require constant extension. The key word here is "should". I'm not sure and the test is not helping.

Basically I don't test that my Export() method "works", I test that my Export() method exports the specific Company that I set up in the unit test.

I have to either get around the need to adjust the unit test, every time I change the Company class.

Or, at a minimum, I need a really good reminder to do it. Something like a breaking unit test...

I thought about something like "asserting that every reference type is not null" in the unit test. But you'd have to do it via reflection and its also not really testing the "Act" part of a unit test. Its testing the "Arrange" part, which feels really strange.

Comment: Your “reminder” is the requirement. The very first thing you should do is add the test that fails.

Comment: That just moves the remembering part one step earlier. My requirement is to add departments. How exactly does that remind me of writing a failing test for company export? It might. It also might not.

Comment: Your *business* requirement is to add departments. This gets mapped onto a series of *functional* requirements, including use cases and potentially a functional specification. The use cases then map onto tests. Downloading is just one more use case. You need to have a rigorous process. This is why [requirements traceability](https://www.inflectra.com/ideas/topic/requirements-traceability.aspx#:~:text=Requirements%20traceability%20refers%20to%20the,iteration%20in%20any%20of%20these) is a thing.

Comment: I see what you mean, but essentially you still just say "someone somewhere should remember". Yes someone should, but im looking for a technical way to force them to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst I think this can be solved in other ways, either in the vein of what John Wu is getting at or a different design approach to what you have, you can solve this using [approval tests](https://approvaltests.com/).

The idea with approval tests is they perform a diff between approved output, against that generated by a test. If the results differ, the test will fail.

As an example, you could setup an approval test based on your `Company` class that can check to see if the shape of the class has changed since the output was last approved. If it has, the test will fail. You should follow the documentation to get setup properly, but here's an complete example just so you can see how it works.

Create a new NUnit test project, and install the `ApprovalTests` NuGet package. Replace the default test with the following, and run it once:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using ApprovalTests;
using ApprovalTests.Reporters;
using System.Text.Json;

[UseReporter(typeof(DiffReporter))]
public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void company_export_succeeds()
    {
        var subject = new Company
        {
            Name = "StackOverflow"
        };

        Approvals.VerifyJson(JsonSerializer.Serialize(subject));
    }
}

public class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You should see a window popup to show you the test failed, with it showing some JSON output in the left pane:

```
{
    "Name": "StackOverflow",
}
```

If you have a look in Solution Explorer, you'll notice two files have been added to the same directory as the test class:

- Tests.company_export_succeeds.approved.json
- Tests.company_export_succeeds.received.json

The approved file, as you might guess, is the version of the data you approve. Right now, that file is empty because we've not approved anything yet. To approve the received file, delete the approved file and rename the received file to `Tests.company_export_succeeds.approved.json`. Run the test again, and it should pass as both files will now have the same content.

Next, modify `Company` to add a new property:

```
public class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Dept { get; set; }
}
```

Run the test again, and it will now fail, because the received output is:

```
{
    "Name": "StackOverflow",
    "Dept": null
}
```

As you can see, it (naively) allows you to see if the class has changed.

The point I'm making is you could use this same process to generate an approved result of an export, so that if the implementation of `Company` changes, the test will fail if the received export differs. The ApprovalTests package isn't limited to just producing JSON, so it should be pretty adaptable.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not make a seperate class that will handle the importing/exporting of your models.

I also don't really see how adding 1 more Company would break your Export() method? Do you have a predefined amount of companies that the Export method takes into account?

**Example for answer**

```
public class ModelParser<T> {
  //Properties and fields here
 public async Task Export(/*File or InputStream*/){
   //Read items from database? and write to file
 }

 public async Task<ICollection<T>> Import(/*File or InputStream or JSON string*/)
 {
    //Import here to database?
    return items;
 }
}
```

Now you can use the ModelParser in your unit tests and that class will be the only class that you need to update if you want to change the logic.

If you have some more info I will change my answer.